# Remove a registry if any column has a NULL value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I would like to delete the rows of a table (Creating other one as the updated version )if any of them has a null value

for example

```
att1  att2  att3
-----------------
1.0    2.9   NULL
23.6   7.9   8.9
43.6   6.9   1.9
```

AND GET

```
att1  att2  att3
-----------------
23.6   7.9   8.9
43.6   6.9   1.9
```

How would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: What do you mean `Creating other one as the updated version `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way

```
DELETE FROM T 
WHERE  att1 IS NULL 
        OR att2 IS NULL 
        OR att3 IS NULL
```

If you have loads of columns at some point this might become simpler.

```
DELETE FROM T 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   (VALUES(att1), 
                             (att2), 
                             (att3)) V(att) 
               WHERE  att IS NULL)
```

You might also consider something like

```
DELETE FROM T 
WHERE att1 + att2 + att3 IS NULL
```

but that could cause unneeded problems with overflow errors potentially.

Comment: One more possibility: `WHERE (att1=att1 AND att2=att2 AND att3=att3) IS NULL`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all columns are numbers...

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE att1+att2+att3 IS NULL
```

Comment: This would delete rows where **all** are null. Not **any** are null.